# What does 'to sound off as soon as you arrive' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

One of the channels that my boss created in [slack](http://slack.com) states

> Since we're separated by distance but needs to work together, we need to know who's IN in a given day. Use this channel **to sound off as soon as you arrive** for work, and before you leave after work.

Does saying `Hello` is sufficient enough so that my boss will know that I arrive already?

Comment: Yeah, he just means speak up by whatever means when you start working.  You could add a bit of a greeting.

Comment: "Sound off" is a term from military drills and the like.  As the soldiers stand in line they say, in turn, "one, two, three..." so that each soldier has a number and a count of those present is known.  Presumably the equivalent in your case would simply be some sort of text message saying "I'm here".  Except that he wants you to somehow notify everyone when you leave as well.  There may be a special facility in Slack to make this easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack has better ways to indicate that you're there.  You can set yourself 'away' or not available, but if not and you're logged in, your boss should expect you're there and available.

Maybe he's trying to use it as a way to see when you've shown up to work.

Comment: Yes, I think so and maybe something like some sort of logs, because if I send a message it will log my message and the time that I've sent that message.

Comment: Yeah, I'll wait a little more to see more answers then choose the best. :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Sort of a roll call, then.

It would be prudent in this case to include your name when you speak up. Anyone can say "Hello," but only Cary Bondoc can say "Cary Bondoc here." So that the boss knows it's you. You're in, bright-eyed and bushy-tailed, and ready to tackle problems, overcome obstacles, and perform feats and exploits and all.

Comment: I don't know exactly how "slack" works, but I'd have thought it would be much the same as any other place where you can post messages online. (As with this comment, where it's totally unnecessary for me to "sign" it with **FumbleFingers** :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I have no idea how "slack" works, and I'm not sure I want to know, either. I think it's just boring. Suppose those "messages" were vocal, though? Or telepathic? What would you have Cary Bondoc do then?

Comment: If "slack" is indeed a system for recording and replaying telepathic messages, I think we should all be very interested indeed. Personally, I'd be fascinated to know whether such a system would automatically and inherently enable me to understand the thoughts of someone who only spoke languages that I don't, and vice-versa. My guess is *not*, but that's because I endorse the "strong" version of the [Sapir-Whorf hypothesis](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/sapir-whorf-hypothesis) (i.e. - without language you can't really *think*, just "emote").

Comment: Better to save your prudence for something else.  Slack is a messaging system, showing messages sent and who sent them. So if you say, "Hello", you don't need to say who you are - that will show as your message right next to your name.  Unless you want it to show: Cary Bondoc said "Cary Bondoc here", identifying you as a newb.